# Gerar Script MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde.

Utilizo o MySql Workbench 6.3.
Preciso gerar o script para criação do banco de dados local para publicar no servidor. 
É completamente inviável criar tudo novamente na mão pois a base é enorme.

Como posso fazer isso??? Gerar um script para criar a base de dados??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe este procedimento simples [Exportação do Banco via MySQL WorkBench](https://www.hostnet.com.br/info/exportacao-do-banco-via-mysql-workbench/)
onde você exporta seu banco utilizando o *Data Export* e é gerado um arquivo no local onde você informar.

### Procedimento

---

**1 -** Acessar o *MySQL WorkBench* e iniciar a conexão com o Banco de Dados;

**2 -** Ao acessar o Banco, vá na aba de *“Management”* do lado esquerdo do programa e clique na opção *“Data Export”*;

**3 -** Em seguida, na tela que aparecer, faça os seguintes procedimentos:

**3.1 -** Selecione o Banco de Dados que deseja exportar;
**3.2 -** verifique as tabelas dele do lado direito;
**3.3 -** Marque a opção *“Dump stored Procedures and Functions“*;
**3.4 -** Marque a opção *“Dump Events“*;
**3.5 -** Marque a opção *“Export to Self-Contained File”*;

> Selecione o local em que deseja salvar o Banco de dados, clicando no
> botão dos 3 pontinhos (…).  Não esqueça de dar um nome para o arquivo
> do Banco *(Ao fazer isso verifique se o caminho e o nome estão
> corretos no campo da localidade)*;

Por fim, clique em *“Start Export“*.

Comment: Na mosca!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Valeu Matheus.